# Order of adding reactants on growth of Cu

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, ph

I am reading the following [paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019MRE.....6f5033V/abstract) which details the steps to control growth of Copper. They fabricate Copper powders from $\ce{CuNO3, NaOH, and C6H8O6}$. Specifically, in this paper they add the sodium hydroxide first to the copper nitrate solution and then they add the ascorbic acid. The chemical equations that occur are $$\ce{Cu(NO3)2 + 2NaOH -> Cu(OH)2 + 2NaNO3}\tag{1}$$ 
$$\ce{Cu(OH)2 + C6H8O6 -> Cu + C6H6O6 + 2H2O}\tag{2}$$

My first question is if the order of adding the acid and base was switched: first ascorbic acid was added to copper nitrate and then sodium hydroxide was added, would it yield the same products as (2)?

My second question is how could I calculate the theoretical pH of the overall reaction if I add 0.1M $\ce{CuNO3}$, 0.5M $\ce{C6H8O6}$, and 0.1 M $\ce{NaOH}$ following the procedure of the paper?

I am thinking that since NaOH is a strong base while ascorbic acid is a weak acid, the pH will be dominated by NaOH. Therefore, I think the pOH would be -log(0.1M $\ce{OH- from NaOH}$) and so the pH would be 14-1 = 13. However, I know this is too high a pH so my method is wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: Now is the time to finally learn, how is pH calculated in trivial and non trivial cases. Google and Wikipedia are good guides.

Comment: Uhh I know how pH is calculated